# How can programmatically we know file sharing is enabled or not in Mac OS X using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have spent 2 days to find the status of file sharing programmatically using Objective C. We can enable the file sharing using system preferences using SharingPreferences. File Sharing Preference pane store at /System/Library/PreferencePanes location. Can we retrieve file sharing status information from PreferencePanes classes?. if then how can we retrieve?.

Can we get file sharing status from system stored plist file, in which plist file status maintains?

OR Any other API of Objective C through we can get the file sharing status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the `ServiceManagement.framework` by checking the status of the appropriate launchd daemons.

```
@import ServiceManagement;

NSArray  *allJobs =  (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(SMCopyAllJobDictionaries(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd));
NSArray  *labels = [allJobs valueForKey:@"Label"];

BOOL AFPSharingIsEnabled = [labels containsObject:@"com.apple.AppleFileServer"];
BOOL SMBSharingIsEnabled = [labels containsObject:@"com.apple.smbd"];

NSLog(@"AFPSharingIsEnabled: %d - SMBSharingIsEnabled: %d", AFPSharingIsEnabled, SMBSharingIsEnabled);
```

`SMCopyAllJobDictionaries` passing `kSMDomainSystemLaunchd` is similar to `sudo launchctl list` in the shell.

Although `SMCopyAllJobDictionaries` is deprecated, there is no replacement and the API works in El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct api to get this status but it can be obtained by other means.

1. Check if port 548 and 445 are open. 548 is used for AFP which is not being used currently but when you turn on File Sharing it turns on AFP also. 445 is the new SMB sharing port.
2. Using NSNetServiceBrowser you can check the list of computers advertising _afpovertcp._tcp. or _smb._tcp. services and see if your computer is among them. You can use the IP or computer name to determine this.

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty implementation of Pradeeps suggestion above.
Basically I want to determine quickly (in 1 second or less) which
to attempt to mount first, afp or smb.

Note that these objects/classes are specific to my implementation:

```
// my specific server implementation details
MboxObject *mbox = [RemoteFileManager mboxForHostString: [aNetService name]];
```

task.targetServerName

NSString *mountedBasePath

```
static BOOL hasAfp;
static BOOL hasSmb;
// delegate callback
- (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing
{
   MboxObject *mbox = [RemoteFileManager mboxForHostString: [aNetService name]];
   if ( mbox && netServiceMboxName && [[mbox name] isEqualToString:netServiceMboxName] )
   {
      if ( [[aNetService type] rangeOfString:@"_afpovertcp"].length )
         hasAfp = YES;
      if ( [[aNetService type] rangeOfString:@"_smb"].length )
         hasSmb = YES;

   }
}
```

kicking off the services...

```
  /////////////////////////// AFP or SMB? //////////////////////////////////
  // quickly determine if afp or smb is enabled
  if ( !mountedBasePath && task.targetServerName )
  {
     netServiceMboxName = [task.targetServerName copy];
     if ( !netServiceBrowserAfp )
     {
        netServiceBrowserAfp = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
        if ( !netServices )
           netServices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [netServiceBrowserAfp setDelegate:self];

        netServiceBrowserSmb = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
        if ( !netServices )
           netServices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [netServiceBrowserSmb setDelegate:self];
     }
     hasAfp = hasSmb = NO;
     [netServiceBrowserAfp searchForServicesOfType:@"_afpovertcp._tcp." inDomain:@""];
     [netServiceBrowserSmb searchForServicesOfType:@"_smb._tcp." inDomain:@""];

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )  // afp is preferred over smb because it is less restrictive (no date/clock restriction)
     {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
        if (hasAfp) break;
     }
     NSLog( @"hasAfp %d hasSmb %d", hasAfp, hasSmb );
     if ( hasSmb && !hasAfp )
        tryingAfp = NO; // don't bother trying afp if only smb found

     [netServiceBrowserAfp stop];
     [netServiceBrowserSmb stop];
     /////////////////////////// AFP or SMB? ///////////////////////////////
  }
```